# How quarks converted into leptons

Tags: standard-model

[image: Pion Plus Decay]
<sub>(source: [gsu.edu](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/particles/imgpar/pidec1.gif))</sub>

Since the charged pions decay into two particles, a muon and a muon neutrino, seems quarks disappeared!,

The decay proceeds by the weak interaction $W^{+}$ and can be visualized in terms of Feynman diagrams.

Isn't it why Quarks are not directly
observed!?

I read somewhere:

> If you are consistent thinker you can go even further and question existence of quarks themselfs then you will not have a problem with fractional charge

Comment: As you have shown how the pion decays by the "annihlation" of the two quarks through the weak interaction, what is your question exactly?

Comment: Quarks aren't observed because of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement ... someone will post about this. Like anna said, in your diagram, the quark and antiquark confined in the pion are annihilated, but that is a different thing, it is not the reason why you don't get single free quarks (except at very high temperatures).

Comment: Sounds crazy but seems Quarks do not exist and Everything is made up of anti leptons and leptons.
and Pion plus decay is just leptons-anti leptons decay

Comment: Fractional Electric Charges were not proposed by QCD, but by the quark model, which came beforehand.

Comment: Normally by "lepton" we mean particles that don't interact via QCD. You seem to be thinking of "integer charged quarks"? That is an old idea, but there are some (difficult) experiments which do seem to falsify it directly. Also, the fractional charges start to make sense in a unified theory like SU(5) grand unified theory.

Comment: Since this is the direction of your thinking I will point out http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0408305 which is a paper trying to unify "iquarks" (author's name for quarks with integer charge) with leptons. That is a paper with no citations and it's probably making a mathematically wrong argument somewhere. If you want to understand what physicists already think, you need to understand fractionally charged quarks, and the SU(5) theory might help too. But people follow their own ideas right or wrong, and maybe you can learn something else from this professional paper even if it is wrong.

Comment: @Mitchell Porter Can you cite a particle that could not be made up of leptons/anti-leptons and must be made up of $\frac{1}{3}$ charge fraction quarks?"

Comment: It's the detailed interaction of the particles with the electromagnetic field which suggest fractionally charged constituents, e.g. http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~kass/P780_L8_sp03.ppt slides 13-14 (decay of vector mesons) or http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0210054 (various other processes).

Answer (score 3):

No. By the same ''argument'', electrons and positrons wouldn't be observed because positronium decays into photons.

Pions are for (anti)quarks more or less what positronium is for elec(posi)trons.